# Dynamic new Object from class - Angular 4

Tags: angular, class, typescript

I try to create dynamic object in function but it is not recognized.

```
function1(object: object) { return new object(); }
```

I call this function with :

```
function1(Test)
```

Test is a simple Class.

```
export class Test {}
```

But I to this error :

```
Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Why do you even need to do something like that in Angular?

Comment: If you don't know the type, you should use `any`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function function1<T>(Clazz: { new(): T }) {
  return new Clazz();
}

export class Test {
}

const o = function1(Test);
console.log(o);
console.log(o instanceof Test);
```

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet ! For information, it's to use dynamic several classes like : function1(Test), function1(Test2), function1(Test3)...

Answer (score 1):

It's not very complicated.

```
export class TestClass {
    constructor(param1, param2) {
        console.log('Creating test class', param1, param2);
    }
}

export interface Constructable<T> {
    new (...params: any[]): T;
}

function createObject<T>(ctor: Constructable<T>, ...params: any[]): T {
    return new ctor(...params);
}
```

Usage:

```
const obj = createObject(TestClass, 'param1 value', 'param2 value');
```

Though the real use case is not very clear as other folks already mentioned.